# Registrar data, hora e IP do usuário no Login

Tags: php, mysql, session

Olá, estou com um problema no qual não consigo solução (e ainda sou leigo em PHP pra ajudar), revirei a internet e não encontrei nada que pudesse me auxiliar, é o seguinte, possuo uma página de login em PHP na qual verifica se o usuário existe em uma tabela, se existir o envia para uma página restrita, se não existir recarrega a página dando um alert de login ou senha incorreto. Gostaria de saber se é possível caso o login esteja correto registrar nessa mesma tabela a hora, login e ip do usuário.

**Código da página de login:**

```
<?php
    include "config/cabecalho.php";
?>
        <?php
            if(isset($_SESSION['msg'])){
                echo $_SESSION['msg'];
                unset($_SESSION['msg']);
            }
        ?>
<body>
<header>
</header>

<font class="titulo-login"><b>ACESSO RESTRITO</b></font>

        <div class="login-pagina">
        <div class="caixa-login">

            <form action="abrir_interno.php" method="post" name="formlogin" id="formlogin">
                <br>
                <br>
                <h1>E-MAIL</h1>
                <br>
                <img src="imagens/iconeavatar.png" class="img-login" />
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="campo-login" placeholder="EMAIL" required autofocus/>
                <br>
                <br>
                <h1>SENHA</h1>
                <br>
                <img src="imagens/iconecadeado.png" class="img-login"/>
                <input type="password" name="senha" id="senha" class="campo-login" placeholder="Senha" required/><br /><br />
                <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="ENTRAR" class="botao">
            </form>
        <br>
      <br>
</div>
<button class="botao-admin" onclick="location.href='index.php'"><img src="imagens/iconevoltar.png" class="img-botao">VOLTAR PARA ÁREA DE CLIENTES</button>

</div>

<?php
include "config/rodape.php";
?>


    </body>
```

**Código da página "abrir_interno.php"**

```
<?php 
// session_start inicia a sessão
session_start();
// as variáveis login e senha recebem os dados digitados na página anterior
$login = addslashes($_POST['email']);
$senha = addslashes($_POST['senha']);
// a próxima linha é responsável em se conectar com o banco de dados.

    include "config/conexao.php";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM usuario_interno WHERE NOME = '$login' AND SENHA= '$senha'";

// A variavel $buscar pega o $login e $senha, faz uma pesquisa na tabela de usuarios

$buscar = mysqli_query($conexao,$sql) or die (mysqli_error($conexao));

if(mysqli_num_rows($buscar)>0)
{
$_SESSION['email'] = $login;
$_SESSION['senha'] = $senha;
header("location:../restrito/restrito_painel.php");  
}else{
    unset ($_SESSION['email']);
    unset ($_SESSION['senha']);
    echo'';
    header("refresh: 0; url=../acesso_interno.php");
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("Erro ao entrar!\n LOGIN ou SENHA incorretos!")
    </script>';

    };

?>
```

Gostaria de saber se nesse abrir_interno.php seria possível registrar data, hora e IP do usuário e se possível, como ficaria?

**Tabela usuario_interno:**
[image: TABELA usuario_interno]

**Estrutura da tabela:**

[image: Estrutura tabela usuario_interno]

Agradeço a toda ajuda desde já!

Ps.: Se meu código estiver com algo errado, por favor me corrija :D

Answer (score 1):

Adicione um `UPDATE table ...` depois do `if(mysqli_num_rows($buscar)>0)` ou crie uma [**procedure**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html) para verificação do login ou ainda utilize o método [**multi_query**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.multi-query.php) do *MySQLI*. Ex:

**MySQL**

```
/* Opcional */
CREATE TABLE `users` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `user` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    `password` VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL
);

/* Adapte conforme sua tabela */

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE checkLogin(IN userName VARCHAR(255), IN pass VARCHAR(255), OUT userId INT)
BEGIN
    SELECT `id` INTO userId FROM `users` WHERE `user` = userName AND `password` = pass;

    UPDATE `users` SET `last_access` = IF(userId > 0, NOW(), "") WHERE `id` = userId;

END $$

DELIMITER ;

/* Opcional */

INSERT INTO `users` VALUES (null, "valdeir", "123456");
INSERT INTO `users` VALUES (null, "valdeir.psr", "1234");
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php

/* Conecta no servidor */    
$conn = new MySQLi("localhost:3307", "root", "123456", "teste");

$user = "valdeir";
$pass = "123456";

/* Executa múltiplas "queries" */
$conn->multi_query("CALL checkLogin(\"{$user}\", \"{$pass}\", @userId); SELECT @userId AS userId;");

/* Acessa o resultado do SELECT */
$conn->next_result();
$result = $conn->store_result();

var_dump( $result->fetch_object() );
```

**PHP sem "Procedures":**

```
<?php

$conn = new MySQLi("localhost:3307", "root", "123456", "teste");

$user = "valdeir";
$pass = "123456";

$queries = <<<SQL
SELECT @userId := `id` AS userId FROM `users` WHERE `user` = "{$user}" AND `password` = "{$pass}";
UPDATE `users` SET `last_access` = IF(userId > 0, NOW(), "") WHERE `id` = userId;
SQL;

if ($conn->multi_query($queries)) {
    $result = $conn->store_result();

    var_dump( $result->fetch_object() );
} else {
    die( $conn->error );
}
```

> Para capturar o **IP** utilize a variável global `$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]`

Answer (score 0):

IP

```
<php?
function ip_cliente() {
     $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';
     $keys=array('HTTP_CLIENT_IP','HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR','HTTP_X_FORWARDED','HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR','HTTP_FORWARDED','REMOTE_ADDR');
     foreach($keys as $k)
     {
         if (isset($_SERVER[$k]) && !empty($_SERVER[$k]) && filter_var($_SERVER[$k], FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
        {
             $ipaddress = $_SERVER[$k];
             break;
         }
     }
     return $ipaddress; } ?>
```

Data

```
<?php

    $DATA=date("m.d.y");
?>
```

Hora

```
<?php
$hora=date('H:i');
?>
```

Depois é fazer um update ao id desejado

Mais formatações de data e hora - *

> https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

*